# Can't serialize and grab data from form using JavaScript and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a simple form where I can add an item, hit submit and grab the data using serialize or .val() but I can't even console log anything once I press submit, what am I doing wrong? I would just like to be able to grab the data.

HTML CODE:

```
    <form >
      <input type="text">
      <input type="submit">
    </form>
```

JAVASCRIPT CODE:

```
$(function(){
  $("submit").submit(function(){
    var data = $("form").serialize();
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your selector `$("submit")` to `$("form")` and give name attribute to input tag . Also add `event.preventDefault()` to prevent default form action

```js
$(function() {
  $("form").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = $("form").serialize();
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input name="text" type="text">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: For some reason I can't console log it I have to alert it? Why would that be? I ran the code snippet and it works here

Comment: Looks like I had to use event prevent default? That allows me to console log it. Does that make any sense to you why that would be?

Comment: While submitting the page it will reload the page

Comment: so how come it works on here under code snipped? I'm just curious.

Comment: You do need `event.preventDefault()`, otherwise your data will be written to the console and then the form will immediately be submitted in the default way -- page reload.

Comment: Ok. I'm still a little confused though because originally your code didn't have it and when I ran it here and checked my console, the data was there showing in the console. What's the diff?

Comment: I think stackoverflow snippet automatically prevent form from submitting

Comment: Gotcha ok makes sense.